# Getting commitid or 'git describe' with git-cvsserver and a CVS working copy

Tags: git, cvs, git-cvs

I have some automated tools that are accessing a git repository through `cvs` and `git-cvsserver`. I would like these tools to be able to see the commit ID of the content that they checked out. Is this recorded somewhere in the `CVS` metadata directory?