# Push multiple branches or tags in one step matching a given refspec to another remote

Tags: git, git-remote

Assume that I have have the following branches

```
refs/heads/master
refs/heads/x
refs/heads/y
...
refs/heads/features/a
refs/heads/features/b
refs/heads/features/c
refs/heads/features/d
..
```

Now I would like push all branches located in `refs/heads/features/*` to another remote (which I have already configured) so they end up on the remote with the same names. But I don´t want to `x` and `y`. Is that possible and if yes how do I do the same thing for tags?

I know `git push --all` can be used but its not quite what I am looking for.

Comment: Can you explain why `git push --all` doesn't work for you?

Comment: I have clarified the post. It should only be branches/tags from a certain depth/refspec.

Comment: Wow, this must be the only `git` question without an answer for 2 years :)

Comment: @lkraav http://stackoverflow.com/q/2284516/4099593

Comment: @lkraav [StackOverflow search says: negative](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+answers%3A0). #2 is from Dec '08

Comment: LOL well played. For the actual problem, I'm thinking good ol shell scripting may be the way. `git tag --list | grep <pattern> | xargs git push <remote>`

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the refspec with a glob.

```
git push <remote_name> 'refs/heads/features/*:refs/heads/features/*'
```

If you want all of the branches to be force pushed then prepend the refspec with a `+`.  If you want to configure always pushing that refspec for the specific remote by default then you can configure it in the local `.git/config` with the following command.

```
git config --add remote.<remote_name>.push 'refs/heads/features/*:refs/heads/features/*'
```

Now when `git push <remote_name>` is used without additional arguments, it will use that refspec by default.

---

Again, here's an example of pushing to the remote with force pushing, instead.

```
git push <remote_name> '+refs/heads/features/*:refs/heads/features/*'
```